# Help me understand this computation of expected value

Tags: probability, proof-explanation, expected-value

From the legendary "A first course in probability" by Sheldron Ross, 7th edition, page 335, example 2j

---

Excerpt from text:

Ten hunters are waiting for ducks to fly by. When a flock of ducks flies overhead, the hunters fire at the same time, but each chooses his target at random, independently of the others. If each hunter independently hits his target with probability p, compute the expected number of ducks that escape unhurt when a flock of size 10 flies overhead.

Solution: Let $X_1$ equal $1$ if the ith duck escapes hnhurt and $0$ otherwise, for $i=1,2,..,10$. The expected number of ducks to escape can be expressed as:

$E[X_1 + ... + X_{10}] = E[X_1] + ... + E[X_{10}]$.

To compute $E[X_i]=P\{X_1=1\}$, we note that each of the hunters will, independently, hit the ith duck with probability $\frac{p}{10}$, so

$P\{X_i=1\}=(1-\frac{p}{10})^{10}$

Hence

$E[X] = 10(1-\frac{p}{10})^{10}$

---

My problem with this solution it that it doesn't seem to account for the fact that two of the hunters might have both aimed for the same duck. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The contrary is true. If all the hunters were aiming for different ducks, the result would be $E[X] = 10(1-p)$, a quite different formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem with this solution it that it doesn't seem to account for the fact that two of the hunters might have both aimed for the same duck. Am I missing something here?

This:

> > To compute $E[X_i]=P\{X_1=1\}$, **we note that each of the hunters will**, independently, hit the ith duck with probability $p/10$, so $P\{X_i=1\}=(1−p/10)^{10}$.

The escape event $\{X_i=1\}$ is the event that none of the ten hunters targets-and-hits the $i$-th duck.   A hunter will either not target, or if target not hit, a particular duck with probability $1-p/10$, and there are ten hunters.

---

Beyond that, the survival of the ducks are not independent; *but* Linearity of Expectation works whether or not the random variables are independent.

So the expected count for ducks that survive, equals the sum of expectations that each duck survives.  $$\mathsf E(X)=10\,(1-p/10)^{10}$$